# C# String Concatenation

Tags: c#, datatable, concatenation

Help me with this Problem in C#, im trying to refine the search of my gridview, this is my code, i want to the user to be able to search values with this format on textbox. (name, description) ex. Food, Ice Cream, then it will filter all the food with description of ice cream. Thanks.

```
((DataTable) gridTestCodes.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
        string.Concat("name like '%{0}% + description + '%{0}%'", 
                      txtSearch.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question exactly?

Comment: What does 'Concat' do? You most likely look for 'String.Format'

Comment: i want to the user to be able to search values on textbox with this format. (name, description) ex. (if he/she types Food, Ice Cream) then it will filter all the food with description of ice cream. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean string.Format instead??

Comment: i have tried, it doesnt work. `code `((DataTable)gridTestCodes.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("name like '%{0}%, description like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''")); `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `concat` in place of `format`. Also, your query is wrong. You're using `+` instead of `AND`, there's a single quote missing after first `'%{0}%`, and `description + '%{0}%'` doesn't make sense. Try this:

```
((DataTable)gridTestCodes.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    string.Format("name like '%{0}%' AND description like '%{0}%'", 
                  txtSearch.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
```

Or try just querying on name first and then adding in description once this works (also should the `.Replace` be removing the quotes all together?):

```
((DataTable)gridTestCodes.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
         string.Format("name like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text.Trim().Replace("'", string.empty));
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to enter name then description seperated by comma try:

```
var name = txtSearch.Text.Split(',')[0].Trim().Replace("'", string.empty);
var description = txtSearch.Text.Split(',')[1].Trim().Replace("'", string.empty);

((DataTable) gridTestCodes.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
        string.Format("name like '%{0}%' AND description like '%{1}%'", name, description);
```

Note that the above code will throw an exception if the input string **does not** contain a comma. So you may want to add a check for that.

Comment: You query is wrong. You're using `+` instead of `AND` and `description + '%{0}%'` doesn't make sense.

Comment: have tried and "name like '%{0}% and description like '%{0}%'" still no results.

Comment: See my edit to answer, does just querying on name work?

Comment: yes, the code does work, but how can i make it like this whenever type the name then coma then description the gridview doesn't produce query, i wanted to be like that. (name, description)

Comment: @KevinRodriguez See edit to answer, you need to use `Split(',')` to split the input string in two.

Comment: @KevinRodriguez Great!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) instead. `string.Concat` just concatenate your strings, it doesn't format them.

And your expression syntax doesn't seems right. You need one more single quote after your first `{0}` and you need to use `AND` or `OR` between your criterias.

```
string.Format("name like '%{0}%' AND description like '%{0}%'", 
               txtSearch.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
```

Comment: thanks, that does work, but how can i make like this, if the user search for name and add "," + the description it should filter results (name, description) with coma

Comment: @KevinRodriguez I don't understand your statement. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: the code does work, but whenever i type the name then coma then description the gridview doesn't produce query, i wanted to be like that.